# Do I have to report lawsuit winnings to taxes?

Tags: class-action

If I am a defendant in a class action lawsuit, and win a certain amount of money, do I have to report the earnings to the IRS?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the nature of the suit and settlement. It's best to read the docs at the IRS: [Publication 4345 (Rev. 12-2016) - Settlements — Taxability](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p4345.pdf)